# order by then group by

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-5.7

how can i first order by and then group by

```
select saf.*
from sm_artists_followers saf,
     sm_artists_meta sam 
where sam.fk_sm_artist_id = 13
  and saf.artist_ID = sam.artist_ID 
  and DATE(saf.scrap_date) = '2023-10-22' 
group by website_ID  
order by saf.scrap_date desc;
```

sm_artists_followers
[image]

Comment: What is the output you expect here?

Comment: Goodness, don't use images of data! just copy/paste the data itself. (Imaging an answer that ws an image of a sql query, very frustrating!) Also, there are 2 tables, supply sample data **per table**  here is a reverse engineered version of that image (but as 1 "table") https://dbfiddle.uk/MNBt51CA - **please** don't use images of data

Comment: Why do you want to ORDER BY _before_ GROUP BY? It wouldn't affect the result. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL you cannot directly perform a GROUP BY operation before an ORDER BY operation. If you want to first order by a certain column and then perform a GROUP BY, you'll typically need to use a subquery

```html
SELECT sub.* 
FROM (
    SELECT saf.* 
    FROM sm_artists_followers saf 
    JOIN sm_artists_meta sam ON saf.artist_ID = sam.artist_ID
    WHERE sam.fk_sm_artist_id = 13 
      AND DATE(saf.scrap_date) = '2023-10-22'
    ORDER BY saf.scrap_date DESC
) sub
GROUP BY sub.website_ID;
```

Comment: Doing the `ORDER BY` _inside_ the subquery is pointless, because the ordering will be lost during the subquery.  Also, doing `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` is almost always an anti-pattern.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you please suggest a better solution ?

Comment: I can't give an answer without more info from the OP.

Comment: The derived table ORDER BY makes no difference at all. And ORDER BY before GROUP BY makes no sense either.